# Calculating the distance with some zip codes fails

Tags: google-maps, google-api-client

The difference between the following two requests is on the destination zip code: the first is 60601 and the second is 60602.

Both 60601 and 60602 are recognized by this [test page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro), but the first one is not recognized by the requests below and the returned status is `"status" : "NOT_FOUND"`.

Why is it possible to calculate the distance between 89139 and 60602, but the distance between 89139 and 60601 fails?

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=89139&destinations=60601&key=<my key>
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=89139&destinations=60602&key=<my key>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible workarounds:

1. add Chicago, IL to the zip code:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=89139&destinations=Chicago,%20IL%2060601

2. add IL to the zip code:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=89139&destinations=IL%2060601

3. add "zip:" to the zip code:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=89139&destinations=zip:60601

(not sure why that zip code returns: `"destination_addresses" : [ "" ]`, but adding pretty much anything to that number yields the correct result)